# Exporting random generated graph into .graphml file in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to export a graph into graphml file using Networkx. The code is as follow:

```
def generate_community_list(N, C):
return list(np.random.multinomial(N, [1/C]*C, size=1)[0])

def generate_rand_graph(num_of_vertices, vl):
num_of_communities = math.ceil(num_of_vertices**vl)
while True:
    G = nx.generators.community.random_partition_graph(
        generate_community_list(num_of_vertices,num_of_communities)
        , 0.9, 0.1)
    
    if nx.is_connected(G):
        break

N = G.number_of_nodes()

for x in range(N):
    G.add_edge(x, x)

return G
```

However, I receive this error in every try. Can you help me figure out what is going on here? I did found a similar error with exporting LFR benchmark graph but it doesnt seem that I could work it out.

[image]